# Pluralize method for different language in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3, pluralize

I am using the `pluralize` method in HTML files to dynamic value which the user can set as per their locale.

i.e. If the user sets label department with the German word "Abteilung",
it will append 's' as per current Rails Inflection rules for pluralize string. So the resulting word will be "Abteilungs" , but there is no such word in German.

I researched , but there are no such inflection rules specific to a certain language.
There may be many such words in many languages so I can't make custom inflection rules.
I am not using I18n or tr8n for internationalizing such words.
Can someone suggest what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Obviously use one of plenty `i18n` gems. Rails internal pluralization is about transparent transform between class names, file names and other internal stuff. It’s not meant to be used as `i18n` engine.

Comment: what is your expected word?

Comment: We use Tr8n for internationalization. but few word are set by user in Application & those words, we don't want to be get translated by tr8n because those are dynamic words so admin set those words.